# Safari strips tags from XML parsed with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, parsing, safari

Safari is consistently showing some weird behavior which is best demonstrated with a code example (in JavaScript):

```
var xml = "<whatever><status>success</status><title>interface update</title><details>just an example</details></whatever>"
var $jquery_xml = jQuery(xml);
var $jquery_xml.html();
```

The final line should return:

```
<status>success</status><title>interface update</title><details>just an example</details>
```

However, it *actually returns*:

```
<status>success</status><details>just an example</details>
```

The  tag has been erased! Any ideas on why, and how I can get around this while still using jQuery?

Comment: maybe its because `<title>` is a special tag that its use on the head section just a hunch :)

Comment: Hi, I'm of the same opinion as Val. It also fails on IE8, but works on Firefox. If you change the tag to `<titles>..</titles>` it works on all of these browsers, including Safari.

Comment: I think that's it, too. But it's kind of worrying, because plenty of XML documents have <title> tags, and other tags that appear in HTML. I'm not sure that's just cause for deleting them -- it's valid XML, right? Maybe I should look into parsing with something other than jQuery on Safari?

Comment: Valid XML but not valid HTML. What do you expect from jQuery when asking it to convert XML to HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery has a [built in XML parser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/), that would probably better serve you.

```
var xml = "<whatever><status>success</status><title>interface update</title><details>just an example</details></whatever>";
var $jquery_xm = jQuery.parseXML(xml);
```

Comment: `parseXML` has only existed since jQuery 1.5, but this is the way to go. One note: the object you get back from `parseXML` is an XML `Document` object, which you need to pass to `$()` to turn it into a jQuery object that you can then query and traverse.